# How can I parse this txt file by omitting certain undesired elements?

Tags: python, parsing

I am currently an intern working a company. I was asked to parse some log file and include only useful details.

The file I have is something similar to:

--Just an example file with zero relation to the business--

```
#Saturday Logs

#Item                  #NumberofItems   #Price
Glue                   2 bottles        $1.99
Pencil & Eraser pack   1                $2.45
Sharpener (M)          2                $3.99
-Omit-
Markers                2 packs          $4.44 -sale
```

What I want to output will look like this:

```
Glue                   2 bottles        $1.99
Pencil & Eraser pack   1                $2.45
Sharpener (M)          2                $3.99
Markers                2 packs          $4.44
```

However the only code I have written so far is:

```
lines = file_input.readlines()

for line in lines:
    word = line.split()
```

I want to try and split apart the strings inside my word array to get rid of -omit-and -sale and the first couple lines of the file but I am stuck and have extremely limited experience in this matter. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write code that reads a line, then skips if if the first character tells you the entire line should be ignored. The code also zaps any strings like `-sale`.

Something like this:

```
for line in open('myfile.dat'):
   if not line.rstrip():
      continue  # skip blank lines
   if line[0] in ('-', '#'):
      continue  # skip lines with these prefixes
   line = line.replace('-sale', '')
   print line,
```

(Thanks to Martijn Pieters for the bugfix!)

Comment: Empty lines contain the newline character still; `if not line.strip()` would work, `if not line` would not.

Comment: The OP also wants to remove any instances of the text `-sale` from within a line, if I understand correctly.

Comment: @nekomatic Yes that is also something I'd like to remove. Also, if I wanted to add a comma in between items and fields how would I go on about doing so?

Comment: The answer above has been edited to show how to remove the `-sale` text. How are the columns separated at the moment - is it a tab character, or multiple spaces?

Comment: They are multiple spaces.